# How can I auto align desktop icons on right side?

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I keep my docky dock on left side of desktop and it overlaps desktop icons and their names when intellihide mode is on. Is there a way to align desktop icons on right side always, mac style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes `gconf-editor` will reveal additional options.  In this case, there's nothing relevant in the apps/nautilus section.

This issue was queried on launchpad a couple of years ago : 
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/48705, but there was no bug filed subsequently.

Your only option is to manually align your icons.

Comment: Too bad. Now I remember there was some screenlet that displays folder contents in a movable widget much like the default widget that comes with KDE. Is there a way to disable desktop icons completely?

Comment: Yep, in gconf-editor go to apps/nautilus/preferences and untick "show desktop".  No more icons.

Comment: there was a bug reported on the actual nautilus bug tracker according to what I read on ubuntuforums, but its old and got nowhere - because the gnome developers figure "too many options" - silly, but, it's gnome :/

Comment: Just Curious, Does the Unity Launcher in Natty have similar problem when auto hide is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this on GNOME. It has been requested in a bug report and on Ubuntu Brainstorm, but no traction has been made on it.

You would have to manually align the icons, or move your dock.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do to move icons on the right side of the deskop (Mac style) is to install screenlets and start "folderview" and set it to show the desktop folder, then you can adjust the screenlet on the right side of your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `iconic` you could modify the script to reorder the icons from right to left. Additionally iconic will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.