# "clean up by name" to the right, like on a mac

Tags: icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I auto align desktop icons on right side?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20728/how-can-i-auto-align-desktop-icons-on-right-side)

Hi,

How do I "clean up by name" so that my icons are sorted from the right instead from the left as it is now.
I have ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
If you right click in your desktop in ubuntu you get a list where you can "clean up by name".

[image]

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20728/how-can-i-auto-align-desktop-icons-on-right-side