# Changing which monitor/desktop files download to

Tags: multiple-monitors, files, downloads, location

I just installed Ubuntu after using Mint for a year or so and I am in love to say the least.

One issue I had with Mint that I never really researched was that when I download files or copy them to my desktop, they always appear on my left monitor.

The way I'm set up is that my laptop is in a dock in the middle and I have a monitor on the left and right.  I use my laptop screen as my primary desktop with my unity launch bar and would like if files would appear their when downloaded/copied.

Sorry if this is a mundane question and though it seems small it would be awesome if I could accomplish this.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I auto align desktop icons on right side?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20728/how-can-i-auto-align-desktop-icons-on-right-side)

Comment: @SylvainPineau: OP wants the files to be shown on his Laptop which is in the middle of his setup. Are you sure the answer given there would work in this case?

Comment: @Aditya: So far it seems that there's no solution to this question (see the possible duplicate)

Comment: @SylvainPineau: Yes I saw the link. I thought you might be referring to the answer which suggests to use screenlets. But, I am not sure if we can consider both the questions as dupes since the requirements are quite different. I would suggest to leave it open with the link to that related question.

Comment: After some continued searching, it seems like others have a similar type of issue to what I'm experiencing.  When minimizing applications that go to the system tray, they will only appear on the system tray on one monitor(left one).  This also happens to me, and I'm sure it happens for everyone using Ubuntu.  Though this issue is different I believe that it's related in the sense that even though you can set your 'primary monitor', it's not quite your 'primary desktop'.  I'm not sure if this has been fixed in 14.04 or not.  It's not a huge deal but it is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

On say Google chrome you can change the place where you would download files. Say you have a file called downloads on the right monitor you can change the place to /desktop/downloads. If you are using any internet browser there is a settings which may have where your downloads folder is. Hope I helped.

Edit: This is not a mundane question as there is no such thing as a boring small question. Never think that. As everyones thoughts are important.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'm okay on the where the download location is - I'm more concerned with which desktop it's downloading/copying to.  This is my setup: http://i.imgur.com/ZUEEQ2V.jpg

As it is currently all downloaded/copied files will go onto Desktop 2, I want them to by default go to Desktop 1.

Comment: @AliensBrah Are you working with different workspaces or are is it just different spaces. as I am a little bit familiar with the workspaces but I am still a newbie to ubuntu. Also I think that the alternate screens are just extensions of your primary computer and It may be the case of you cannot do it. Now do you want to have the downloaded files moved to the desktop 2 for convenience or is there some ulterior motive to moving downloads there.

Comment: I'm only using one workspace, just spread across 3 monitors.  I typically have a VM running on my left monitor(Monitor 2).  I then have a bunch of miscellaneous applications/browsers running on my right monitor(Monitor 3).  On my middle monitor, I usually just have a terminal running and so when I download things, it's more convenient for me if they go to my middle monitor.  Right now everything by default will go to the left monitor and I need to minimize my VM and drag it over to my center desktop.  Though this isn't a huge deal, it'd be awesome for me if I could have stuff go to the middle.

Comment: Going back on my previous statement I think you just need to create a folder in the middle named whatever you want it and just change its directory. Thats all the advice that I could give. As said before I am a novice that does not know any solutions to this for now. I might research this and come back to it at another point

Comment: Ah yeah, I suppose if there is no other way to change this then that would be an okay work around.  This may be related or not but on my 'system tray' icons, the default ones appear on all 3 monitors.  But icons from applications I've installed like XChat & Spotify only appear on the left monitor.  So it seems like Ubuntu thinks that my left monitor is somehow my 'primary'.